# Realtime linux colored tail with filtering support for tomcat?

Tags: linux, colors, tail

I am looking for a tail, gui or console based, that would be able to filter and color messages from tomcat based on their level: `INFO, WARN, ERROR, CRITICAL`.

Another feature that is quite importat would be to be able to scroll back, a lot.

- So far I eliminated Splunk (commercial solution), as far I fount it too hard to setup.
- tried `multitail` but scrolling seems too awakard, also no filetring detected
- tried `mtail` - no filtering, coloring
- good older `tail`

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [`ccze`](http://freecode.com/projects/ccze) for that

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat.log | ccze
```

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: I wrote a tool called [TxtStyle](https://github.com/armandino/TxtStyle) that does something similar as the options mentioned earlier. You can run it as follows:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | txts --regex '\d+'
```

You can also define named styles in the config file (`~/.txts.conf`) and use it like so:

```
ifconfig | txts --name ifconfig
```

(`ifconfig` style is defined out of the box)